# How to delete few rows using Ebean(PlayFramework)?

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I need to delete few rown according with given data:

```
DELETE FORM mytable WHERE cond1 = 1 AND cond2 = 2;
```

But I found no methods which allow to delete object with given way. There is method that allows to delete a single object(`Model.delete()`), but it is not effective way for list of object.
I do not want to execute a raw SQL request because it's depends of SQL dialect and it's risky for SQL-injections.

So what it a right way to implement this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to give [Ebean.createUpdate()](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Ebean.html#createUpdate(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) a try.
As the javadoc describes, this method accepts an ORM update string.

> The orm update differs from the sql update in that it you can use the
>   bean name and bean property names rather than table and column names.

For example:

```
Update<Customer> upd = Ebean.createUpdate(Customer.class, "DELETE Customer WHERE email=:email");
upd.set("email", "someone@somewhe.re");
return upd.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [com.avaje.ebean.SqlUpdate](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlUpdate.html) for this. i.e.

```java
SqlUpdate down = Ebean.createSqlUpdate("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 123");
down.execute();
```

Also it's possible to update many - see also [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13025093/1066240)

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```
Ebean.deleteAll(UserType.find.all());
```