# How do I perform a SQL batch delete with the Playframework 2 / Ebean?

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean, playframework-2.2

I need to delete some rows from table according with some criterias.
SQL query should be like this:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE cond1 = 1 AND cond2 = 2
```

But I found no such methods. I can delete a single model:

```
model.delete();
```

Or I can get a list of models accorsing with given critetias:

```
Model.FINDER.where().eq("cond1", 1).eq("cond2", 2).findList();
```

Off course, I can get list of models and delete them in the cycle, but this is very bad solution. Instead of one SQL-request I getting potentially unlimited SQL-requests.
I also do not want to execute raw SQL code because it's can break SQL cross-platform compatibility.

It really is frequently task.
Is that true that Play Framework has no means of work with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed deleting objects one-by-one is bad solution, fortunately Ebean allows you to perform [`SqlUpdate`](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlUpdate.html) like:

```
SqlUpdate tangoDown = Ebean.createSqlUpdate("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 123");
tangoDown.execute();
```

see: [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13025093/1066240) for parametrized queries.

Comment: FYI: Also note version Ebean version 6.5.1 has added ... delete(query)  - https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/398