# Ebean equivalent of SQL Query

Tags: java, sql, ebean

I want an Ebean equivalent of this SQL Statement

```
SELECT A,B,C FROM TABLE1 WHERE A BETWEEN "X" AND "Y"
```

I have the Ebean [Avaje Documentation](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery.html) with simple queries example

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please share some tips of improvement before DOWN VOTING a question. :)

Comment: You know what you want and you have a tutorial to teach you how. Is this info just not in the tutorial or something?

Answer (score 0):

De facto it's in [API](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlQuery.html), also there are some samples in my answer to ... [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13017411/1066240) :)

**Edit:**

To perform what you want with Ebean API, just use... `between(propertyName, value1, value2)` i.e.:

```
List<Foo> foos = Foo.find.where().between("bar", 5, 10).findList();
```

And if you want to get only specified `foo`, `bar` properties, additionally use `select("comma,separated,list")`

```
List<Foo> foos = Foo.find.select("foo, bar").where().between("bar", 5, 10).findList();
```

Note, that using finder with `select("list")` **always** adds the `id` property to the list (and also discriminator if used), even if they are not explicitly added to the list.

Comment: @thanks biesior I actually referred your question as a part of my research.. unfortunately I am restricted to use Ebean model example.. (dbfinder is finder object) dbfinder.find.where().ilike("name")..   I am searching for something like this dbfinder.find.between(). thanks again :)

Comment: Ach, didn't realize what are you asking about then