# Play + Ebean how to keep primary keys while editing record?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am trying to use Play Framework with Ebean. I have quite simple Java class `Subject`:

```
@Entity
public class Subject extends Model {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    public final int id;
    public String name;

    public Subject() {
        id = 0;
    }

    public Subject(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And also I have simple edit form (`views.subjects.edit.scala.html`):

```
@(subjectForm: Form[models.entities.Subject], id: Int)
@import helper._
@main("Subject") {
@helper.form(action = routes.Subjects.save(id)) {
@helper.inputText(subjectForm("name"),'_label -> "Name")
<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Save">
<a class="button" href="@routes.Subjects.index()">Cancel</a>
}
}
```

Field `id` is not editable (it's primary key), that's why I don't like to show it in form input elements. So, when I saving edited `Subject`, I need to do something like

```
public static Result save(int id) {
    Form<Subject> form = subjectForm.bindFromRequest();
    if (form.hasErrors()) {
        flash("error", DATA_ERROR);
        return badRequest(edit.render(form, id));
    }
    Subject subject = form.get();
    if (id == 0) {
        // Add new record case
        subject.save();
    } else {
        // Edit existing record case
        Subject old = Subject.find.byId(id);
        if (old == null) {
            return notFound(NOT_FOUND);
        }
        old.setName(subject.getName());
        old.save();
        flash("success",
                String.format("Subject %s, %d saved",
                        old.getName(), old.getId()));
    }
    return redirect(routes.Subjects.index());
}
```

I have only one question. Is there any ways to get `Subject` instance from `subjectForm` with correct (original) id? Make additional requests to database for updating record seems like not a good solution. But when I gettting instance from `subjectForm` id always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to show it use a `hidden` field in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value='@subjectForm("id").value' />
```

BTW: Fetching object and updating it is natural way for doing it, alternatively you can use [SqlUpdate](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlUpdate.html) of Ebean for direct query [like in these samples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13025093/1066240)

edit: If you will pass hidden ID you can also try to save object in shorter version like:

```
Subject subjectFromForm = subjectForm.bindFromRequest().get();
subjectFromForm.update(subjectFromForm.id);
```

Comment: Seems like there is no helper for hidden input fields. So, I can write form code without any helpers to reduce size of HTML code? Right? All I need to do is set correct `name` and `id` tags. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Helpers only allows you to generate HTML tag(s) anyway you can do it also yourself (as you can see), and yes in form element `name` attribute is most important, if you won't use it it won't be sent by browser

Comment: May I ask you one more question? Why I should set the `subjectFromForm.id` parameters? Value of id from fetched object is not enought?

Comment: There was some problem with `obj.update();` before in Play with Ebean and `obj.update(id);` was a solution, so in this case it's just easiest to use `obj.update(obj.id);` as we have it binded