# Ebean's SqlQuery with PostgreSQL's "INSERT ... RETURNING"

Tags: postgresql, playframework, ebean

I'm using ebean ORM in Play framework (for Java). Trying to write a `SqlQuery` in raw SQL (`INSERT ... RETURNING id`), something like this:

```
SqlQuery sql = Ebean.createSqlQuery("INSERT INTO T1 (f1, f2, f3) VALUES (1, 2, 3) RETURNING id");
SqlRow row = sql.findUnique();
Long id = row.getLong("id");
```

It's weird that the query actually returned the insertion id (var `id` actually contains a valid value that increases each time I run the above codes). But there's nothing in `T1` table.

Trying to figure out why, I turned on PostgreSQL's debug5 logging. It seems like the `sql.findUnique()` was put into a transaction and the transaction get rolled back.

So, how could this be possible?

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017411/how-to-create-custom-insert-into-query-in-ebean).

Comment: @Sivakumar Yes actually that's at the top of search result. The problem is that I want to issue a INSERT which will return a value, so I assume I need SqlQuery but the result is not as expected.

Comment: Well, you definitely can't do this with SqlQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Ebean.createSqlUpdate()` instead of `Ebean.createSqlQuery()`?

Comment: I need to get the returned id so SqlUpdate is not an option because there's no way to fetch the result.