# Ebean: How to create a column for a getter without a property

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.4

I wan't to be able to store computed values from Java in my database.

For example, I might have a Person class that with a `firstName` and a `lastName`. I may want a getter that returns the the total length of the `Person`s name, without it being an actual property.

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String firstName;

    public String lastName;

    public Int getNameLength() {
        return firstName.length() + lastName.length();
    }

    public Person (String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

So if I create a new `Person` like so:

```
Person bob = new Person("Bob", "Roy");
bob.save();
```

Then we should end up with this in the table:

```
|  id  |  first_name  |  last_name  |  name_length |
====================================================
|  1   |    "Bob"     |    "Roy"    |      6       |
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please for the sake of [Old Gods and the New Gods](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Faith_of_the_Seven) don't do this**

Doing something like this would totally mess up your database. You *will* run into problems sooner or later. Looking at your profile you obtained a CS degree so you definitely had your databases course. Remember the [Second normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) and the [Third normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) and how you will break this if you have attributes which depend on other attributes.

What you should do is to have either a transient field (marked with `@Transient`) or you can use the getter and provide the information from there. Every time you need to access the `name_length` you will call this getter but you won't store the information in the database.

Even if you want to calculate the length outside of your application, you can still use some database function for this - [like length](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html).

---

**Edit based on the requirement mentioned by the OP:**

In JPA there are two ways how you can declare the columns - either on fields or on methods (getters/setters). It would go like this:

```
@Column(name = "complex_calculation") // Due to some bad requirement
public Integer getNameLength() {
    return fisrtName.length() + lastName.length();
}
```

However you mentioned Ebean in your question and Ebean is not regarded as the reference JPA implementation. There is a good chance this is not yet supported but you can try it in your specific case.

There is another way which is proven to work. You define your model like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Model {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private Integer nameLength;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // getter for first name and last name with @Column annotation

    @Column(name = "complex_calculation")
    public Integer getNameLength() {
        return firstName.length() + lastName.length();
    }

    public Person (String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        updateComplexCalculation();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        updateComplexCalculation();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        updateComplexCalculation();
    }

    private void updateComplexCalculation() {
        this.nameLength = firstName.length() + lastName.length();
    }
}
```

The important part is the `updateComplexCalculation` method. When the constructor is called and on every setter-call you invoke this method to update the *complex* property. Of course you should invoke it only on setter-calls which are needed for the computation.

The following code:

```
Person p = new Person("foo", "bar");
p.save();

Logger.debug("Complex calculation: " + p.getNameLength());

p.setFirstName("somethingElse");
p.save();

Logger.debug("Complex calculation: " + p.getNameLength());
```

yields then:

```
[debug] application - Complex calculation: 6
[debug] application - Complex calculation: 16
```

Comment: I remember my normal forms well, and I agree with you. But sometimes requirements come up. The client wants the field in the database, but they don't want it to be just a computed value by the database. This is for performance reasons. 

This is not the actual use-case, so length is not going to work. The rules for calculating these fields are significantly more complicated and exist and is used in our Java code. We need these as fields when generating reports with SQL, and it would be preferable to not duplicate business logic in a bunch of SQL views.

Comment: I see your point. Although I still don't like the idea, I have updated my answer with a way to make this work. My assumption is that you would have to define a property when using Ebean. It should work without a property on Hibernate.

Comment: Accepted your comment. The fact that he getter for the name length was manually calculating the values threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong about property in the model? Just make it `private` add the `public` getter but without setter, finally override `save` and `update` methods.

```
private Integer nameLength;

// BTW shouldn't you also count the space between first and last name?
public Integer getNameLength() {
    return firstName.length() + lastName.length();
}

@Override
public void save() {
    nameLength = firstName.length() + lastName.length();
    super.save();
}

@Override
public void update() {
    nameLength = firstName.length() + lastName.length();
    super.update();
}
```

---

If you still want to avoid property in the model, you will need to use custom SQL query (probably also within the overridden `save/update` methods), like showed [in other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13025093/1066240) or [Ebean's docs](http://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/SqlUpdate.html), note that will perform at least 2 SQL queries per each save or update operation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Anton and biesior for giving me some ideas.

Rather than override the `save` or `update` methods, we opted for a private variable that is recalculated when the variables it's dependent on are updated.

```
public class Person {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer nameLength;

    public String getFirstName() { 
        return firstName; 
    }

    public String getLastName() { 
        return lastName; 
    }

    public void setFirstName() {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        calculateNameLength();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        calculateNameLength();
    }

    private void calculateNameLength() {
        nameLength = getFirstName().length + getLastName().length;
    }

}
```

This has several benefits over the suggested methods of updating the value in the `save` or `update` methods.

Recalculating in the `save` or `update` method means we need to call one of those methods every time we set a field on the object. If we don't, the `nameLength` will get out of sync. I couldn't, for example, change the Persons `firstName`, and then use the `nameLength` to do something else without first persisting the object to the database.

Furthermore, using the `save`/`update` methods couples the objects state to the Ebean. The ORM is for persisting object state, not for setting object state.

Comment: Given the fact that the solution you decided to go for is actually the one I proposed, you could just accept my answer :)

Comment: No problem, glad that you were able to solve your problem! Happy Playing :)